# Unix dividing C application into cores automatically?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have done a C application that just uses no threads neither processes. Its just a simple single-threaded application that runs for 1 hour or so computing algorithms.

Thing is, running under Windows this application just runs under one core, (I have an i3 processor with 4 virtual cores therefore it uses 25% of the cpu constantly).

However, when I run it under Mac, application is divided into cores automatically and it is used 100% of cpu.

Do you know the reason why?

Thanks

Comment: "However, when I run it under Mac, application is divided into cores automatically and it is used 100% of cpu." It's supposed that some of the libraries that you've used evolves threading. Come and provide more details and we could determine why it behaves like this.

Comment: OSX does not concurrently run a single thread application over 4 cores, something else is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a difference in the default way CPU use is reported between the operating systems.  OSX is reporting 100 percent of 1 core; Windows is reporting 25 percent of 4 cores.  While it may seem mathematically wrong for a program to use more than 100 CPU on a system, it also seems strange for a compute-bound program to be reported as 1.56 percent CPU on a 64 core server.  Assuming identical processor and memory speeds, please check wall-time of a complete run to verify the program is performing similarly on each system.

Comment: Slight nitpick: windows 8 reports the CPU usage relative to the base CPU frequency. So if you have a quadcore 2.5ghz processor with turbo boost to 3.2ghz, windows reports that as 32% CPU usage. It caps out at 100% though.